# How to use a new window to let the user input data about an item in a list?

Tags: javafx

In my main window there is a list of items which the user can add to. I want to have a dialog window open each time they add an item where they can add information about that item such as the name of it etc., and then it will be added into the list on the main window with all provided data. I would also like them to be able to click on the item later and open the same dialog in which they can edit the data.

I am having trouble figuring out how to implement this, mainly in how to carry the information from the dialog back to the main window, and in the case of editing the item carrying the initial information already in the list to the dialog for it to be edited. What would be a good way to do this?

I am sure there is a common method for it since this is a very common feature in many software applications, I've just been unable to find guidance on how to do it.

In a previous application I sent the index of the item in the list to the dialog as well as a struct or enum of some kind containing the information between the windows so it could insert the item into the list at the correct index with the correct data, but this became very messy and clunky.

```
@FXML
private ListView<String> taskListView;

public void addTask() {

    taskListView.getItems().add("New");

}

public void editTask() throws Exception {

    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("EditWindowView.fxml"));

    Stage stage = new Stage();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
    stage.setTitle("Edit Task");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

}
```

I open the dialog with the editTask method so this is where I would put in information that needs to be carried back and forth, I'm just really unsure of how to do that.

I know this is quite a broad question so please bear with me. Even if anyone could provide a link to a tutorial which teaches something like this that would be greatly appreciated. If you need any more information from me please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Rather than using a `Stage` and trying to make it function like a dialog, you should use the [`javafx.scene.control.Dialog`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html) class. See [this article](https://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/) for more information about using `Dialog`s. Note if your items are simply `String`s, then using a [`TextInputDialog`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TextInputDialog.html) will probably be easiest.

Comment: @Slaw thank you very much, looks like it's exactly what I need.

Comment: If you want to continue working with `Stage`, you could use `showAndWait` which returns after the window is closed... `Dialog` would be the cleaner approach though.

Comment: @Slaw how should I go about creating a dialog with multiple input types? For example I would like to have a text input as well as two inputs to get dates.

Comment: look at the custom dialog on the article that @slaw referenced ..

Comment: @kleopatra I'm just confused on how to use that because in declaring it they use "Pair<String, String>", how would I make one that will have multiple different data types?

Comment: If the items are distinct, you should probably have separate dialogs for each input type. Either that, or use `TextInputDialog` and attempt to parse the `String` into a date. But using a separate dialog with a `DatePicker`  would make things much easier.

Comment: you have to model your data, f.i. a MyReturnType and create that based on the input fields. Anyway, I think you have to take a step back and learn a bit more of java/fx basics .. @Slaw don't think so: the list should contain those model items (to be defined), and then the dialog would provide custom content that can be used to create/edit the details of the item. At the end of the day random guessing, though .. the question is _really_ too broad ;)

Comment: @kleopatra I was assuming (I know, bad!) that the different types were unrelated to each other, in which case having one dialog attempt to handle all types would be a mistake. If all the different types are related to a single entity, then I definitely agree with your comment.

Comment: @kleopatra oh yeah I definitely do need to learn more, I keep realising just how much I don't know... thanks a lot for your help though :)

Comment: @Slaw the data types are all related to one entity, my bad -- should have made that more clear.

Comment: yeah, I'm aware that it's a bit hard at the beginning :) Possible steps to break it down a) create a class Task with some properties b) make your list contain some hard-coded items of type Task c) write content pane to input the properties (no dialog yet, just to get the feeling) d) sync the pane content with the list's selection e) now you are ready to move the editor into a dialog - if you are stuck on any of the steps, come back with a concrete question (including a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem). Happy coding :)